# Is it Possible to Set a "Minimum Distance from Left" Value for a DIV?

Tags: html, css, window, position

I'm building a page which is static vertically, but allows the space between page elements to grow when the user expands the window. This works fine. However, I'd like to set a minimum width for the page so that the elements stop shrinking together when the user resizes the window below a predetermined width, to prevent them overlapping.

I think the solution is probably simple, but I can't figure it out. I've set the DIV which contains "Recent News" to 48px from the right, absolutely positioned, and I'd like to set something similar so that it never gets closer than 800px (or whatever) from the left edge of the window.

I can post code snippets, but not sure what CSS would be useful right now.

You can see the problem I'm having here: http://www.cjfoote.co.uk/news/index.html

Comment: Have you tried using the min-width property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/min-width ?

Comment: If the problem is just the overlap, you should float the main column, or give both columns an absolute position and set the widths in percentages. Not sure if that answers your question though

Answer (score 3):

Use the css property `min-width`.  This will make it so that when under certain width, it will not get any smaller.

#### See Also

[CSS min-width Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `min-width` is the correct property.

However, you need to change your layout a little bit in order to use it, because `#centre`, `#left`, and `#right` are all absolute.

You can do better with having the `#centre` positioned `static` or `relative`, with enough `padding-right` and `padding-left` to place the absolutely positioned `#right` and `#left` inside it. Then `#centre` will naturally consume the rest of the space and you can use `min-width` on the `body`.